# Multiple Choice Form for beer, pizza or both with dynamic price and direct Paypal Url

Tags: forms, url, paypal, payment

I want to solve an everyday problem:
My friends and I meet and they order beer and pizza and one person pays for everything. The day after, the paying person should get their money back via Paypal. My goal now is to create a form where each person can choose whether he has used pizza, beer or both and send the corresponding price via Paypal.

I am quite able to write a small web application that solves this problem, but I wanted to look for other options.
First I came across google forms with script app. But there is no possibility to edit the answer to the form.

Next I thought of a simple spreadsheet that lists the different possibilities with a Paypal button where the receiver and price is adjusted.
My question here is:
Can one create a Paypalbuttton without JS or PHP, where the price and or receiver are changed?

In general I would like to hear your ideas on this topic.

Yours sincerely,
J gallus

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this and with only clinet side integration(i assume you are focusing only client side integration) you can only dynamically change the amount but not the receiver/ payee. In only client side interation its not possible and you may end paying multiple transaction fee with this approach. you may look into this [PayPal Split pay](https://www.seetickets.com/content/paypal-bill-split) 
or use [vemno](https://venmo.com/) payment option. what you really need is an peer-to-peer payment model.